# PyGears is not generating output HDL files

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pygears

This is the code I run, and it's not generating output HDL files:

```
from pygears import gear
from pygears.typing import Ufixp, Uint
from pygears.sim import call
from pygears.lib import drv, collect


@gear
def gain(din: Uint[8], *, val) -> Uint[8]:
    return din * Ufixp[0, 8](val)

res = []

drv_din = drv(t=Uint[8],seq=[3,2,5])

gain(drv_din, val=0.5, __sim__='verilator') \
    | collect(result=res)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyGears will only generate HDL files when necessary for the simulation or when directly instructed to do so via `hdlgen()` function (see an example below). In your case you did specify that the `gain` module should be simulated using Verilator HDL simulator, but you never called the simulator to execute. In other words, you need to call the `sim()` function at the end of your script, which you should import like this: `from pygears import sim`

However, when PyGears is not given a folder where to store the files, it will automatically create one inside the Temporary folder of your OS (`/tmp` for Ubuntu). In order to generate files local to the script, you should specify it via `resdir` argument of the `sim()` function:

```
from pygears import gear
from pygears.typing import Ufixp, Uint
from pygears.sim import sim
from pygears.lib import drv, collect


@gear
def gain(din: Uint[8], *, val) -> Uint[8]:
    return din * Ufixp[0, 8](val)


res = []

drv_din = drv(t=Uint[8], seq=[3, 2, 5])

gain(drv_din, val=0.5, __sim__='verilator') \
    | collect(result=res)

sim(resdir='./output')
```

On the other hand, if you are only interested in HDL files, than you need not run the simulation, you can just call `hdlgen()` directly (which is also called under the hood in the previous example):

```
from pygears import gear, Intf
from pygears.typing import Ufixp, Uint
from pygears.hdl import hdlgen


@gear
def gain(din: Uint[8], *, val) -> Uint[8]:
    return din * Ufixp[0, 8](val)


gain(Intf(Uint[8]), val=0.5)

hdlgen('/gain', outdir='./output')
```

Notice how I removed all the verification components (`drv()`, `collect()`, etc.) since I am not simulating anything with this script. This was just to provide a minimal example, and `hdlgen()` could have been called within the first example with all the verification components present.